# Iterate data in anonymous variable

Tags: linq

I have a DataTable containing some data, and I am going to fetch some data from it using Linq to datatable.

The query looks like this:

```
var requiredData=dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(row => row.Field<byte>("id") == 1)
  .Select(x=> {
    id = x.Field<int>("id"),
    YYYYY = x.Field<string>("ColumnName2"),
    ZZZZZ = x.Field<string>("ColumnName3")
  }
);
```

Now, Please how do I iterate-through "requiredData"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop:

```
foreach (var item in requiredData)
{
    // TODO: use item.id, item.YYYYY and item.ZZZZZ here
}
```